# Arrangement of legend and size of headers for seaborn subplots

Tags: python, seaborn, legend, diagram, subplot

I have problems with the arrangement of the legend and the font size. As you can see on the picture, the legend is in the diagram and not next to it (it should be on the right). I would also like to change the font size of the heading and the axes. Unfortunately, I can only do this if they are not placed next to each other. Does anyone have an idea how this could work? Is the error perhaps due to the way I made the subplot?

Many thanks already!

```
#Create Boxplots for beliefed ranks 
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

figure_Grank = sns.boxplot(x='Treatment',y='Believed Rank within own Gender',data=df_fig, hue="sex", palette='vlag_r', ax=axes[0]).set(title="Beliefed Rank within own Gender")
plt.legend(title="Sex", bbox_to_anchor=(0.75, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., fancybox=True)


figure_rank = sns.boxplot(x='Treatment',y='Believed Rank',data=df_fig[df_fig["Period"]==4], hue="sex", palette='vlag_r', ax=axes[1]).set(title="Beliefed Rank whithin own Group")
plt.legend(title="Sex", bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., fancybox=True)



plt.subplots_adjust(left=0,
                    bottom=0.2, 
                    right=2, 
                    top=1.2, 
                    wspace=0.2, #this is the horizontal space between the diagrams
                    hspace=4) #this is the vertical space between the diagrams  #0.8
```

[image]

Comment: The legend in the left plot is automatically created by seaborn.  `plt.legend(...)` operates on the "current ax", which happens to be `axes[1]` in both cases. Things are easier if you'd use `axes[0].legend(...)` and `axes[1].legend(...)`.

Comment: When I do so, I get the Error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'legend'".

Comment: So I tryied figure_Grank = sns.boxplot(x='Treatment',y='Believed Rank within own Gender',data=df_fig, hue="sex", palette='vlag_r', ax=axes[0]).legend(title="Sex", bbox_to_anchor=(0.75, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., fancybox=True)

Comment: `'list' object has no attribute 'legend'"` means you tried `axes.legend(...)` instead of `axes[0].legend(...)`. If you do `sns.boxplot(...).legend(...)`, you get the same as `ax = sns.boxplot(...)` followed by `ax.legend(....)`.

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments. Instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68711902/edit) your question and add all relevant information.

Comment: Oh sry, I didn't knew that. Now it works!